# Convert a list of time in PDT to UTC in python

Tags: python, timezone

I have a list start_time containing about 400 series of times which I converted to time format in the form:

```
(2017, 10, 22, 15, 19, 23)
(2017, 10, 22, 15, 19, 35)
(2017, 10, 22, 15, 19, 35)
(2017, 10, 22, 15, 19, 35)
..
..
..
```

This time is in PDT. I want to convert this list in UTC timezone.

The code I have to convert the list to the time format:

```
y=[tuple(dparse(x).timetuple())[:6] for x in start_time]
```

The code I have to convert this to UTC:

```
y_utc = [tuple(dparse(x).astimezone(pytz.utc).timetuple())[:6] for x in y]
```

Using this I get the error:

```
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not tuple
```

I also tried using pendulum:

```
y = [pendulum.parse(x, tz='US/Pacific') for x in start_time]
y_utc = [z.astimezone("UTC") for z in y
```

But then either the kernel stops or it shows that astimezone is not iterable.

So I need the final list in the utc timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This attempt is using `datetime` and `pytz` modules. First parse them as 'US/Pacific' and then simply convert them to `UTC`. Also, you need to unpack tuples(using *) and then provide them to `datetime` constructor.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

time_stamps = [(2017, 10, 22, 15, 19, 23), (2017, 10, 22, 15, 19, 35)]

my_timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')

for time_stamp in time_stamps:
     date = datetime(*time_stamp).replace(tzinfo=my_timezone)
     print (date.astimezone(pytz.utc))
```

Comment: This almost solved my problem but when I add the result to a list instead of printing it, it just shows one of the value and repeats it.